# Google Pay for Passes

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, google-pay

I am currently using the following example project from Google https://github.com/google-pay/s2ap-quickstart-csharp however I am not able to get the process working in any way.

I have adjusted the config to use the correct account details and private key. However when I click on the Insert buttons a call is made that never returns. It seems to be getting stuck on this line `var loyaltyObj = woService.Loyaltyclass.Insert(loyaltyClass).Execute();` the execute command does not appear to ever resolve and no error message is received. I have checked the console as well as the network to see if there are any errors but nothing obvious has stood out so far.

Does anyone know if this library is faulty or if the example code is out of date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this library and yes it's works :)
But you must:

- Add your private key in the solution (key.p12)
- Edit the "Web.config" file, insert your ServiceAccountId and your IssuerId.

Note: To retrieve this information read the documentation: https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/basic-setup/get-access-to-rest-api

Comment: Can provide me a solution so that I create google generic passes?